# VB.NET access modifiers change automatically

Tags: vb.net, access-modifiers

Whenever I change any property value of any control in VB.NET, other control access modifiers change automatically. Like "`Friend WithEvents dgvQuestion As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView`" to "`Private WithEvents dgvQuestion As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView`".

What might be the cause and How can I avoid that ?

Comment: Hi @Abhay, Did you find any solution regarding this?

Comment: I've been having the same problem in one particular form of my project.  In my case, I've chalked the quirkiness up to being ancient code that has undergone several visual studio version upgrade conversions.  I'd also be curious to know if the solution was ever found, though.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Modifiers property in the Properties window is set appropriately.  This may be causing the change.

Comment: I checked them and they are set to "FRIEND". They change to "PRIVATE" in MyForm.Designer.VB, when I make any changes in the MyForm.VB[design] view.

Comment: Very weird, not sure what's going on.  Sorry.